# Stop grep after one result on Solaris

Tags: grep, solaris

I need to return the most recent value from a log file. I know this value will always be near the end of the log file, and I only ever want one result.

On Ubuntu I've accomplished this with `tac dhcp.log | grep macaddress -m 1`, and on Solaris I've almost replicated this with `tail -r dhcp.log | grep macaddress`, but it runs through the entire file which is quite large and takes too long. Is there any way to kill grep after the first result so that it doesn't run through the entire file?

Comment: Have you tried adding a further pipe to a process such as `sed '1q'` or `head -n1`? That should send a `SIGPIPE` to the writing process, I think

Comment: I did not. I am new to unix so getting as far as I did on Ubuntu was a big win for me. I tried Jlliagre's solution below and it worked perfectly though.

Comment: It's worth noting that gnu grep's -m option doesn't cause grep to SIGPIPE the sender. it just stops reading the stream, other programs are free to continue reading from it. something the awk/sed answers won't be able to replicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNUgrep installed (eg `/usr/bin/ggrep` or `/opt/gnu/bin/grep` on Solaris 11, `/opt/sfw/bin/ggrep` on Solaris 10) then you have the `-m` flag.

Instead of `grep` you could use `sed`

```
sed -n '/macaddress/{ p
q
}'
```

Comment: I feel like this is the best answer in most cases, as ggrep would be the best possible answer. However in my case I used Jlliagre's solution as the intent of the command was clearer to me.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an alternate solution based on `awk`:

```
tail -r file | nawk '/macaddress/ {print;exit}'
```